# Bootstrap dropdown-menu won't open inside div class=container

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use quiet complex multi-level navigation and I need to wrap content of the dropdown in the bootstrap container, so it's max height fit's the grid height. However, when I do so, dropdown doesn't open at all.

See the fiddle (I put the comment right after the issue causing div, so if you comment that div, the dropdown will open normally): https://jsfiddle.net/s5ug07t4/7/

Here's the HTML with the container:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main menu item</a>
      <div class="container"><!-- That's the issue causing container -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu row">
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">abc</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">def</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">ghi</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">abc</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">def</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">ghi</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">abc</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">def</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">ghi</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">abc</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">def</li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">ghi</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      </div><!-- /That's the issue causing container -->
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here's my updated fiddle, so you see exactly what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/s5ug07t4/9 Currently it's not a valid HTML because there is div container inside ul, however, moving it one level up wrapping ul with that container breaks dropdown so it doesn't open anymore.

Comment: Placing your container there will make the default bootstrap dropdown go wrong. You could enclose all your navbar in the container. I'm not posting this as an answer because I cannot see your entire page and verify it works as you would expect. Your js fiddle works ok with this edit though.

Comment: It wouldn't work, as background color behind the navigation wouldn't be 100% of the width.